# GitLab change permission of protected branches

Tags: gitlab

We recently migrated to GitLab Self Hosted (V14.3.0)

We migrated 100+ repos to Gitlab and then we realized, by default only maintainers have write access to Gitlab protected branched.

Is there a way to change the following setting in one shot for multiple repositories or we will have to manually change for every repository?

[image: Permission]

We want to change "Allowed to merge" from "Maintainers" to "Developers + Maintainers"

In the main group we have set it to the following, I was hoping that this will make it work but no luck -
[image: Group Permission]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well manually will be a bad approach, but the GitLab API offers a lot of functionality regarding that problem. I will not write the script, but i will outline you the APIs you can use and why you use them.

1. Fetch a list of all projects you want to change - the [Projects API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#list-all-projects)

   ```
   GET /projects
   ```

   With this endpoint you will receive a list of all the projects within you instance, on which the user has access - be aware that this is a paginated request - so just calling it once will not be sufficient.
2. Adapt the Protected branches - the [Protected Branches API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/protected_branches.html)

   With the project IDs from the first part you can now query each project and change the protection. We ended up with first deleting the protection and recreating them, because it has proven to be easier.

Anyway i recommend to automate this with a script, and do it rather sooner than later. As some projects might start with custom protections, and this can make the migration harder.

Comment: Have you tried it?  Is url encoding of this  &allowed_to_push=[{user_id: 1},{user_id: 2}] or is that a typo? Maybe they meant to do json &allowed_to_push=[{"user_id": 1},{"user_id": 2}]

Answer (score 1):

> the GitLab API offers a lot of functionality regarding that problem

Actually, [GitLab 15.6](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/11/22/gitlab-15-6-released/#update-access-levels-from-protected-branch-api) (November 2022) does provide said API:

> ### Update access levels from Protected Branch API
>
> Previously, the UI was required to update the access levels of protected
> branches. The API required you to unprotect, then reprotect, a branch when
> updating its access levels.
>
> Now, the
> [protected branches API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/protected_branches.html#update-a-protected-branch)
> enables you to directly update which users or groups are `allowed_to_push`, `allowed_to_merge`,
> `allowed_to_unprotect`, and more.
>
> This one-step method decreases the risk of a bot
> changing this setting and leaving a branch unprotected.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/protected_branches.html#update-a-protected-branch) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/20229).